# CSS: How do I arrange 3 elements into columns with the middle element filling in between them?

Tags: css, dynamic-resizing

I have 3 elements I want to arrange into columns.  I want the left and right elements to stay fixed widths and align to their respective edges of the page, but the middle element I need to fill in the space between them.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Age old question, solved by the geniuses at ALA: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/holygrail/